# Is there a way to reset the login password on big sur using the terminal?

Tags: terminal, password, big-sur

As the title says…

Searching online the way to do it is while logged in as the user:

```
sudo security set-keychain-password -o oldpassword -p newpassword /Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Or:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -passwd /Users/username newpassword
sudo security set-keychain-password -o oldpassword -p newpassword /Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

These methods don’t seem to work on big sur.

I just prefer using the terminal coming from a Linux background.

Also has the added benefit of not wearing down your touchpad and stepping though a million GUIs.

That’s why I got a Mac, I was sick of windows, how slow it is and the constant updates (Mac is definitely better).

Error message:

```
security: error changing password for "/Users/apple/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db": The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
```

I just tried logging in using the exact same password I used for the `-o` option and it worked

`/Users/apple/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` does not exist so I manually added it using touch but I get the same message

Comment: It‘s three or four dialogs and few clicks, don‘t think you need to worry about wearing out any hardware. Anyway, what does „not work“ mean: error message, no effect, something else?

Comment: Yeah I’m just not into using the GUI, I’ll grab the error message

Comment: You can‘t create login.keychain by touch‘ing it. Find out where it actually is and use the correct path.

Comment: Only `login.keychain-db` exists, no need to be a smartass, it’s clearly said in the guide that you’ll find it in `/Library/Keychains` I tried using `mdfind` and `locate` to find it and they failed, if you have big sur I dare you to have a go

Comment: Find didn’t turn up anything except the file I created, got any other bright ideas? Or do you just enjoy being a smartass @nohillside?

Comment: We don’t see your screen so we don’t know which guide you are following. But try `man security`.

Comment: So smartass, `sudo security login-keychain` returns `~/LibraryKeychains/login.keychain-db` man keychain does nothing to help, if you don’t know what you’re talking about just stay silent? Thanks for the useless advice @nohillside

Comment: Calling people names won‘t help in getting answers. Please add the link to the guide if you want to provide context. Anyway, as you now found the path to the keychain, does changing the password work if you use the correct path?

Comment: wow you are seriously blind, that was the first path I tried go and see my question... Seriously if you don't know just don't try and 'help,' thank you for your very helpful suggestions, I appreciate it very much, you kind soul

Comment: Well, I may be mistaken but the path you pass to the security command in your question is not the same you got from `security login-keychain`.

Comment: you are indeed mistaken my helpful fellow, look at my error message:

`security: error changing password for "/Users/apple/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db": The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.`

and now you will say 'oh type the right password,' well sir I typed the exact same login password and I still got that error, just ad I wrote in the question, now since you have given me so many helpful suggestions, I will give you one.

Before offering generic suggestions please actually know what you're talking about, and read the question thoroughly :)

Comment: Its always a very good strategy to insult the people that are trying to help!

Comment: @x_841 telling me to do things I’ve already done, and saying thing like ‘man security’ isn’t helping its insulting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use that convoluted cmd this one is better, it changes sudo and login pass, like you'd expect `sudo passwd` to do: except on Mac it doesn't.

```
sysadminctl -adminUser <user> -adminPassword <pass> -resetPasswordFor <user> -newPassword <newPass>
```

Comment: Does it also change the keychain password?

Comment: I’m assuming yes since the GUI login resets and without keychain password being updated you can’t change the GUI login

Comment: When I tried this on Big Sur, I thought it didn't work after I saw this: "sysadminctl[20929:1457646] resetting password for <my name>. (Keychain will not be updated!)" But despite the message, my keychain password was changed.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried on 11.4:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/$USER 'newpassword'
security set-keychain-password -o 'oldpassword' -p 'newpassword' /Users/$USER/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

will change the password of the user currently logged in,

```
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/otheruser 'newpassword'
sudo security set-keychain-password -o 'oldpassword' -p 'newpassword' /Users/otheruser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

will change the password of user `otheruser`.

In both cases, `dscl` prompts for the old password (of `$USER` or `otheruser`, respectively).

Comment: thank you @nohillside for the earnest attempt at helping this time... I guess you just needed a little push before you stopped with the generic suggestions... I will try this on a new user, I'm still using the user this laptop came with, I got this error `<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14090 (eDSAuthFailed)` but I appreciate your response thank you

Comment: I didn’t get prompted like you said